# Hay alguna manera de simplificar esta función? (agregar un item a un carrito de compras)

Tags: javascript

Después de estar luchando con esta función para que haga lo que yo quería, vengo a preguntarles si hay un método mas simple y practico para desarrollarla.
Lo que logré básicamente es lo siguiente:
Los productos que se agregan son objetos, el carrito es un array. Si el array es = null, se agrega directamente el 1er producto. Cuando ya no es null, se evalúa si el producto no se encuentra en el array (para que no agregue varias veces el mismo prod. por separado, la idea es ir aumentando la cantidad y no el prod. por separado). Hasta que pude lograr que me funcione estuve un día entero. El código es el siguiente:

```
function agregarAlCarrito(producto) {
    let contenidoLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemsDelCarrito"));
    let contador = 0;
    if (contenidoLocal == null) {
        CarritoDeCompras.push(producto);
        localStorage.setItem("itemsDelCarrito", JSON.stringify(CarritoDeCompras));
        alert("Primer producto agregado al carrito."); 
    } else if (contenidoLocal != null) {
        for (prop of contenidoLocal){
            let match = prop.nombre.includes(producto.nombre);
            if (match == true) {
                contador += 1;
            }
        }
        if (contador >= 1){
            alert("El producto ya se encuentra en el carrito.");
        } else {
            CarritoDeCompras.push(prod);
            localStorage.setItem("itemsDelCarrito", JSON.stringify(CarritoDeCompras));
            alert("Otro producto agregado al carrito ");
        } 
    } else {
        alert("Ocurrió un error.");
    }
}
```

Como ven, si el array del carrito en el localStorage es != null, un for...of comprueba que no exista ya el prod. Para poder evaluar si todo el bucle es true o false, tuve que poner un contador. Cada vuelta del bucle busca si el nombre de lo guardado coincide con el nombre de lo que se quiere guardar, si todo da false, quiere decir que el prod. no estaba en el carrito, por ende se agrega. Si alguno da true, entonces hay coincidencia, el contador suma 1 y no se agrega nada. Hay algún método mas simple para hacerlo? Recién estoy arrancando con javascript así que no conozco muchos metodos y props aún. Saludos.

Comment: Tal vez te puedes ahorrar el `for of`, con el método `includes` pero tendrás que pasarlo todo a un array (no se si también acepte un JSON)

Answer (score 2):

He tratado de simplificar tu código y presentarlo de forma más limpia.

```
function agregarAlCarrito(producto) {
    // Contenido será igual al arreglo que es encuentra en el almacenamiento local.
    // O a un arreglo vacío si no hay nada.
    const contenido = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsDelCarritos')) || [];
    // No me parece que String.prototype.includes() sea apropiado, 
    // ya que el método retorna true si un string se contiene dentro de otro. 
    // Es decir, por ejemplo, retorna true para el caso de 'teléfono' y 'tele'
    const item = contenido.find(x => x.nombre === producto.nombre);
    
    // Si el producto ya está en el carrito, entonces mostramos un mensaje y retornamos.
    if (item) {
        alert('El producto ya se encuentra en el carrito');
        return;
    }

    
    carritoDeCompras.push(producto);
    localStorage.setItem('itemsDelCarrito', JSON.stringify(carritoDeCompras));
    
    // Mostramos un mensaje de acuerdo al numero de productos en el carrito.
    if (carritoDeCompras.length === 1) {
        alert('Primer producto agregado al carrito.');
    } else {
        alert('Otro producto agregado al carrito.');
    } 
}
```

Lo que también he tratado de hacer es generalizar el problema, para evitar tener tantos casos especiales.

Igual quería notar que los métodos `String.prototype.includes()` y `Array.prototype.includes()` realizan búsquedas completamente diferentes. El primero, como ya mencione, busca un string dentro de otro. Mientras que el del Array, busca un elemento en un arreglo.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, resuelves de una forma muy sencilla la tarea y aseguras que la variable sea un arreglo vacío cuando no existe en `localStorage`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ver mi código!! Voy a escribir tu sugerencia y ver que tal me va, pero a simple vista ya puedo notar que me lo resumiste de manera impecable! muy buena la data del "includes". El problema que estaba enfrentando yo, era ver de que manera efectiva entrar al array [] y poder buscar dentro de cada object {} la prop nombre y compararla con la misma prop pero del parámetro ingresado al llamar la función. (podría se id también). Gracias!

Comment: Lo probé y surgió el mismo problema: carrito.js:96 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null
    at agregarAlCarrito (carrito.js:96)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (tienda_listeners.js:1)

Comment: Si o si, primero tengo que evaluar si efectivamente lo que se cargó es null (en el 99.9% de los casos, cualquier usuario que ingrese a la tienda va a tener el carrito null). Al ser null desde el inicio, cualquier búsqueda que quiera hacer dentro del array me va a tirar error.

Comment: Por eso, mi lógica era que si el array era null, hiciera un push del producto directamente (imposible que se pudiera duplicar el mismo prod. si no hay nada aún). Ahora, si ya había algo dentro, ahi si fijarse si lo que se estaba pusheando coincidia con algo ya metido. Voy a modificar un poco tu sugerencia a ver si funciona

Comment: Pero es que el contenido no va a ser nunca null, sino que va a ser un arreglo vacío por defecto. Ya tendrías que mirar si si estas inicializando carritoDeCompras como un arreglo vacío, pues asumiendo que es una variable global. Es decir al definir carritoDeCompras debería ser algo como const carritoDeCompras = []

Comment: Claro, el tema es que siempre estoy usando lo guardado en localStorage. Ese contenido se va a cargar posteriormente en el array CarritoDeCompras = [], que como bien decís, lo inicializo vacío. Si un usuario ingresa a la tienda, el contenido del localStorage va a ser null. El array CarritoDeCompras lo uso como si fuera una memoria volátil, por asi decirlo.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, gracias a todos por tomarse el tiempo de leer y responder. La funcíon quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
function agregarAlCarrito(producto) {
    let contenidoLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemsDelCarrito"));
    if (contenidoLocal == null) {
        CarritoDeCompras.push(producto);
        localStorage.setItem("itemsDelCarrito", JSON.stringify(CarritoDeCompras));
        alert("Primer producto agregado al carrito");
    } else {
        const coincidencia = contenidoLocal.find(item => item.nombre === producto.nombre);
        if (coincidencia){
            alert("El producto ya se encuentra en el carrito.");
        } else {
            contenidoLocal.push(producto);
            localStorage.setItem("itemsDelCarrito", JSON.stringify(contenidoLocal));
            alert("Otro producto agregado al carrito ");
        } 
    }
}
```

El cambio fue de esto:

```
        for (prop of contenidoLocal){
            let match = prop.nombre.includes(producto.nombre);
            if (match == true) {
                contador += 1;
```

a esto otro:

```
        const coincidencia = contenidoLocal.find(item => item.nombre === producto.nombre);
```

Finalmente aprendí la diferencia entre find e includes. Gracias!
El próximo paso es hacer modales para no tener que ver esos alerts horribles del navegador, jeje. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que podrías usar la siguiente lógica:

```javascript
function agregarAlCarrito(producto) {
    let contenidoLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("itemsDelCarrito"));
    
    if (contenidoLocal == null) {
        contenidoLocal.push(producto);
        //lo metemos en un array y lo guardamos en el localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("itemsDelCarrito", JSON.stringify([producto]));
    } else {
        //comprobamos si ya existe en el carrito
        const coincidencia = contenidoLocal.find(item => item.nombre === producto.nombre);
        if (coincidencia != null){
            alert("El producto ya se encuentra en el carrito.");
        } else {
            contenidoLocal.push(producto);
            localStorage.setItem("itemsDelCarrito", JSON.stringify(contenidoLocal));
            alert("Otro producto agregado al carrito ");
        } 
    }
    return contenidoLocal;
}
```

De este modo no dependes de variables globales (`CarritoDeCompras` no sé de donde viene, no es un parámetro que estés usando) y devolvemos el valor del carrito como resultado, con lo que podrías hacer algo como:

```
CarritoDeCompras = agregarAlCarrito(prod);
```

Comment: Gracias Pablo por responder! voy a probar también tu sugerencia a ver como resulta. el CarritoDeCompras es el único array que uso en donde guardo los productos que va seleccionando el usuario. Tengo la tienda en una pag y el carrito en otra distinta (sería el checkout) por eso, al no poder verse el carrito a medida que se agregaban productos, tenia que implementar esta solución de chequear si ya estaban en el array para que no aparezcan repetidos a la hora del checkout (la lógica es que si el cliente quiere mas de uno, aumente la cantidad, no duplicar las instancias de una misma cosa).

Comment: Pablo! Funcionó a la primera.  Cuando modifiqué un poco la sugerencia de JhonRM, quedó escrita como la tuya. Gracias a todos por la ayuda!!